# Knox process consumes all resources in Dataproc master node

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, apache-knox

I try to open a my notebook that is stored in GCS. I create a Dataproc cluster with Jupyter and I connect Jupyter web interface.

When I open my notebook, I get an error(Error 504, there is not more info).

[image]

When I open my notebook, I check the master node and I see there is 'knox' process consumes my cpu(%198) and memory(%100) resources.

[image]

I encountered this situation 3-4 times every week.

Is there anyone who has encountered same issue before?

Comment: It looks like memory leak, did you try `sudo systemctl restart knox` to mitigate the issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried but after re-open same notebook, same issue emerges.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your problem by creating a cluster with Jupyter component, then opened a Python notebook and ran `print('hello world')` many times. Then I sshed into the master node and kept monitoring the Knox process memory usage. Each time I ran the cell, the memory of Knox process increased by ~3M.

Setting `export KNOX_GATEWAY_MEM_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"` in `/usr/lib/knox/bin/knox-env.sh` then `sudo systemctl restart knox` might be helpful, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of your problem.